# How to loop with dynamic list?

Tags: php, html

If variable $single = 1 and variable $double = 2

I want a result like this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IivO.jpg

I try the code like this :

```
<?php
    $Sgl = 1;
    $Dbl = 2;
    $Trp = 0;
?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Room Type</td>
        <td>Room Grade</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Family Name</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $no = 1;
        for($i=0; $i< ($Sgl ? $Sgl : ($Dbl ? $Dbl : ($Trp ? $Trp : 0))); $i++) {
            if($Sgl)
                $room_type = 'Single';
            else if($Dbl)
                $room_type = 'Double';
            else if($Trp)
                $room_type = 'Triple';
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $room_type; ?></td>
        <td>Standart Room</td>
        <td>
            <select>
              <option selected>Mr.</option>
              <option>Ms</option>
              <option>Mrs</option>
              <option>Mstr</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Family Name">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="" placeholder="First Name">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
            $no++;
        } 
    ?>

</table>
```

But it seems the code is still wrong

How to keep the results as the image above?

Any help much appreciated?

Cheers

Comment: what is your issue? and what are your requirement?

Comment: @Amit Rajput, what I want is : If `variable $single = 1` and `variable $double = 2`, then the result like this image : http://imgur.com/U0zxCgI. I have tried like the above code, but it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
    $Sgl = 1;
    $Dbl = 2;
?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Room Type</td>
        <td>Room Grade</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Family Name</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
    </tr>
    <?php       
        $total = ($Sgl * $Sgl) + ($Dbl * $Dbl);
        for($i=1; $i <= $total; $i++) {
            $room = 'Standart Room';
            if($i == $Sgl && $Sgl == 1){
                $no = $i;
                $roomType = 'Single';
            }elseif ( ($i%$Dbl) == 0) {
                if($i == $Dbl){
                    $no = $i;
                    $roomType = 'Double';
                }else{
                    $no = $i - 1;
                    $roomType = 'Double';
                }
            }else{
                $no = $room = '';
                $roomType = '';
            }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $roomType;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $room;?></td>
        <td>
            <select>
              <option selected>Mr.</option>
              <option>Ms</option>
              <option>Mrs</option>
              <option>Mstr</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Family Name">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="" placeholder="First Name">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
            $no++;
        } 
    ?>

</table>
```

**OUTPUT :**

It is same as showing in image.

**Note :**

This answer take variable $single = 1 and variable $double = 2.

**Modified :** This is fully dynamic code. Cheers...

```
<?php
   $counter = 0;
   $first =2; $second = 4; $third = 1; $four = 2; $five = 3;
   $common_fields = '<td>
            <select>
              <option selected>Mr.</option>
              <option>Ms</option>
              <option>Mrs</option>
              <option>Mstr</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Family Name">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="" placeholder="First Name">
        </td>';
?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Room Type</td>
        <td>Room Grade</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Family Name</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
    </tr>       
        <?php 
            if($first){
                for ($i=1; $i <= ($first*1); $i++) { 
                    $counter ++;                   
                    echo "<tr><td>$counter</td><td>First</td><td>First Standard</td>$common_fields</tr>";  
                }
            }

            if($second){
                for ($i=1; $i <= ($second*2); $i++) {
                    if($i%2) {$counter++;}
                    $roomtype = ($i%2) ? 'Second' : '';
                    $room = ($i%2) ? 'Second Standard' : '';
                    $no = (!empty($roomtype)) ? $counter : '';
                    echo "<tr><td>$no</td><td>$roomtype</td><td>$room</td>$common_fields</tr>";  
                }
            }

            if($third){
                for ($i=1; $i <= ($third*3); $i++) {
                    if(($i-1)%3 ==0) {$counter++;}
                    $roomtype = (($i-1)%3 ==0) ? 'Third' : '';
                    $room = (($i-1)%3 ==0) ? 'Third Standard' : ''; 
                    $no = (!empty($roomtype)) ? $counter : '';
                    echo "<tr><td>$no</td><td>$roomtype</td><td>$room</td>$common_fields</tr>";
                }
            }

            if($four){
                for ($i=1; $i <= ($four*4); $i++) {
                    if(($i-1)%4 ==0) {$counter++;}
                    $roomtype = (($i-1)%4 ==0) ? 'Four' : '';
                    $room = (($i-1)%4 ==0) ? 'Four Standard' : '';
                    $no = (!empty($roomtype)) ? $counter : '';
                    echo "<tr><td>$no</td><td>$roomtype</td><td>$room</td>$common_fields</tr>";  
                }
            }

            if($five){
                for ($i=1; $i <= ($five*5); $i++) {                    
                    if(($i-1)%5 ==0) {$counter++;}
                    $roomtype = (($i-1)%5 ==0) ? 'Five' : '';
                    $room = (($i-1)%5 ==0) ? 'Five Standard' : '';
                    $no = (!empty($roomtype)) ? $counter : '';
                    echo "<tr><td>$no</td><td>$roomtype</td><td>$room</td>$common_fields</tr>";    
                }
            }
        ?>
</table>
```

Comment: It's working. It is the same as the picture. Thank you very much.

Comment: I want ask again. For example, there are 5 input variables. they are single, double, twin, triple, quad. it looks like the above code should be changed

Comment: @samueltoh YES. Above code will change. If my answer solve your question or near to your answer, don;t forget to vote

Comment: Ok. Seems the above code is not perfect. When I change the variables, the results does not match. For example, the input variables: `$Sgl = 0, $Dbl = 2, $Twn = 0, $Trp = 0, $Quad = 0;`. The result: http://imgur.com/U0zxCgI

Comment: i know this is not perfect. but matches your result. do one thing. tell me exact what you want. how many variable can be include and all things.

Comment: There are 5 variables.  They are single, double, twin, triple and quad.

Comment: also tell me values of your 5 variables

Comment: The value of these five variables are dynamic. It is the user input

Comment: come on chat, i also have to ask some other question.

Comment: For example : If `$Sgl = 0, $Dbl = 0, $Twn = 0, $Trp = 1, $Quad = 1;`, The result : http://imgur.com/Th3nQ6g.  If `$Sgl = 2, $Dbl = 0, $Twn = 2, $Trp = 0, $Quad = 0;`, The result : http://imgur.com/Q2mUPLa

Comment: Now i got what you want. give me some time. it will take time.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can not chat here. Because my reputation is not sufficient.  If you would like to chat via skype?

Comment: If my reputation reached 15 reputation. I will vote you

Comment: Thanks @samueltoh I am happy you got your answer.

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517387/how-to-multiply-number-until-achieve-single-digit-numbers-and-counting-the-numbe

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<tr>
<td>No</td>
<td>Room Type</td>
<td>Room Grade</td>
<td>Gender</td>
<td>Family Name</td>
<td>First Name</td>
</tr>

<?php
$row_count = 1;
foreach($array as $key => $value):

if($value == 'single'){
    $room_type = "Single";
    $room_grade = "Standard Room";
    $count = 1;
}else if($value == 'double'){
    $room_type = "Double";
    $room_grade = "Standard Room";
    $count = 2;
}

for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++){
    if($i>1){
        $room_type = "";
        $room_grade = "";
    }
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_count; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $room_type; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $room_grade;?></td>
    <td>
    <select>
      <option selected>Mr.</option>
      <option>Ms</option>
      <option>Mrs</option>
      <option>Mstr</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Family Name">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="" placeholder="First Name">
    </td>
</tr>
<?php

}

endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: may i see what is out

Answer (score 0):

Limited information. If you can please tell us your current output that would help. The issue seems to be in your for loop and conditionals. Try something like this.

```
$Sgl = 1; $Dbl = 2; $Trp = 3;
for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    switch ($i) {
        case $Sgl:
            $room_type = 'Single';
            break;
        case $Dbl:
            $room_type = 'Double';
            break;
        case $Trp:
            $room_type = 'Triple';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what I want is : If `variable $single = 1` and `variable $double = 2`, then the result like this image : http://imgur.com/U0zxCgI. I have tried like the above code, but it failed

Comment: "it failed" is ambiguous. Is it a syntax error? Is it a 500? A segfault? Is the output just incorrect? Try tweaking the for loop and conditionals and the variables. Use "echo" to debug your variables.

Comment: the output just incorrect. The output does not match with the picture

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement like this. Just do in this way. Below is your full code.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Room Type</td>
    <td>Room Grade</td>
    <td>Gender</td>
    <td>Family Name</td>
    <td>First Name</td>
</tr>
<?php 
$no = 1;
foreach($array as $key=>$val){        
    for($i=0; $i< $val; $i++) {
        $room_type = $key;
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $room_type; ?></td>
    <td>Standart Room</td>
    <td>
        <select>
          <option selected>Mr.</option>
          <option>Ms</option>
          <option>Mrs</option>
          <option>Mstr</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Family Name">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="" placeholder="First Name">
    </td>
</tr>
<?php            
    }
    $no++;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. But the numbers are not the same. It is not the same to that in the picture. Look here http://imgur.com/U0zxCgI. It's different

Comment: OK, i got your point. Just try my updated answer, this will solve your no. issue also. let me know if works.

Comment: You try to see the latest answer to the above. It is my point

Comment: ok..but in above answer you would need to change code if need arises for more variables.

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517387/how-to-multiply-number-until-achieve-single-digit-numbers-and-counting-the-numbe