# How to multiply number until achieve single-digit numbers and counting the number?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, split

its description like this:

```
persistence(39) == 3 // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
// and 4 has only one digit

persistence(999) == 4 // because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
// 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2

persistence(4) == 0 // because 4 is already a one-digit number
```

I can only make like this :

```
$array = str_split(39);

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo $array[$key]*$array[$key+1];
    }
```

The next I'm confused

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: I like the question. Something else than the boring, always repeating stuff asked under the `php` tag. +1

Comment: @AlBundy Yea agreed! Got a nice chance to pick my brain a little :)

Comment: @DunnoHowToCode you was too quick for me with your answer, but we have now in Europe 05:20 AM and I have a 16 hours working day behind me and my brain is shutting down for now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = str_split('999'); //Your string
$j=0; //Counter for counting the number of iteration
while (count($array)>1){ //When more than 2 indexes in array
 for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){ //Iterate through all permutations
     $array = array_product($array); //Multiplies all numbers in array
     $array = str_split($array); //Split the array up again
     $j++; //Increment counter(as literal as I can sound)
 }
}
echo $j; //Print out the number of times
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521602/how-to-make-triangle-roll-up-with-php

Comment: @samueltoh roberto06 has already provided you with a perfect example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use function recall until it's only has one digit ...

```
$count = 0;
persistence(2,$count);
function persistence($i,&$c){   
     $v = str_split($i);
        if(count($v) > 1){
            $total = array_product($v);
            $c++;
            persistence($total,$c);
        }
}
var_dump($count);
```